# node express request made in post API

Tags: node.js, rest, express

In my node express application I am trying to take a MVC approach so I have moved some logic over to my controller. I am getting the result back that I am expecting from the request call but I am  not able to return them with `res.send()` for some reason. Ultimately, I would like the save the response in the array `access_token` and send it back to the API that was called as the response.

## from my controller:

```
const access_token = []
exports.auth = (req, res, next) => {
  request(options, (err, res) => {
    if (err) throw new Error(err);
    console.log(res.body);
    res.status(200).send(res.body)
  })
};
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

## route

```
router.post('/auth', sonflexController.auth)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `res` objects in your request callback. change the inner callback argument to a different name, e.g. `request(options, (err, response) => {...; res.status(200).send(response.body);`

Comment: Thank you, that was it! I totally overlooked that.